# Finding the Bounds a Location falls in?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have MySQL database of areas in a city. The attributes of each area are: lat , lng, SWLat, SWLng, NELat, NELng.

I need help in writing a query the tells me the area for a given location, which consists of Lat & Lng.

Thanks in advance, Sal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really enough information, but this would appear to fit the bill:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE
myLat >= SWLat AND myLat <= NELat AND
myLng >= SWLng AND myLng <= NELng
```

`myLat` and `myLng` are the coordinates of the location for which you are trying to find the containing region.

Comment: Thank you Andrew. It seems to work. Will update when I am able to extensive tests. I was thinking it would be pretty complex similar to proximity formula. Sal.